# PostgreSQL win32/64 windowless installation without PgAdmin3?

Tags: windows, postgresql, installation, pgadmin

A win32/64 installer for our software use

```
{'--unattendedmodeui':'minimal',
'--mode':'unattended'}
```

parameters in subprocess for an official PostgreSQL installer:

http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#windows

http://get.enterprisedb.com/postgresql/postgresql-9.1.2-1-windows.exe

Is it possible to disable PgAdmin3 installation with a parameter or using any other win32/64 prebuilt PostgreSQL binaries?

Comment: http://pginstaller.projects.postgresql.org/silent.html

Comment: Yep, I had read that and it seems that .msi installer is obsoleted, at least I can't find any .msi binaries on postgresql pages. Official win32/64 .exe installer isn't compatible with msiexec.

Comment: if you want, I still have an *.msi from a project that I worked on, let me know where to upload those(3 files, 2 *.msi and 1 redist.exe) and I'll give you the link. Note that the version of postgres is 8.3, if you want a more recent version, I can't help you

Comment: I really want to stick to the official release of every dependency in the software. I also have these files somewhere on the disk. For now let's say pgAdmin3 isn't really **so** big problem. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> *or using any other win32/64 prebuilt PostgreSQL binaries*

You can download the [ZIP archives](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload) and then embed these steps into your installer:

1. unzip the archive
2. create the windows service user acount (if wanted/needed - not needed since 9.2 any more)
3. run `initdb` with the approriate parameters
4. run `pg_ctl register` to create a Windows service

Before integrating the ZIP archive you can remove all unwanted components from it (e.g. pgAdmin, debug symbols).